# Move PictureBox with Arrow Keys?

Tags: vb.net

I use the following code to handle positioning of certain controls in my Form;

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    'Sub detects which arrow key is pressed
    Dim strControlName As String
    ' Get the name of the control
    strControlName = Me.ActiveControl.Name
    Dim aControl = Me.Controls.Item(strControlName)
    If strControlName <> "PrintButton" Then
        If keyData = Keys.Up Then
            aControl.Location = New Point(aControl.Location.X, aControl.Location.Y - 1)
            Return True
        End If
        'detect down arrow ke
        If keyData = Keys.Down Then
            aControl.Location = New Point(aControl.Location.X, aControl.Location.Y + 1)
            Return True
        End If
        'detect left arrow key
        If keyData = Keys.Left Then
            aControl.Location = New Point(aControl.Location.X - 1, aControl.Location.Y)
            Return True
        End If
        'detect right arrow key
        If keyData = Keys.Right Then
            aControl.Location = New Point(aControl.Location.X + 1, aControl.Location.Y)
            Return True
        End If
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

I also have a PictureBox that I allow a Drag n Drop image into;

```
Private Sub pbSig_DragDrop(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles pbSig.DragDrop
    Dim picbox As PictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)
    Dim files() As String = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())

    If files.Length <> 0 Then
        Try
            picbox.Image = Image.FromFile(files(0))
            pbSig.ImageLocation = files(0)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Problem opening file ")
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub pbSig_DragEnter(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles pbSig.DragEnter
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    Else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there a way I can make the PictureBox "movable" using the arrow keys?  I can't use a KeyPress event on the Form since I am already using it elsewhere.  I was hoping I could set a focus on the PictureBox or allow the user to do a "+Arrow" event.

Also, if I make the PictureBox move, is the dropped image going to move with it?

Comment: The code you have is working correctly. You have just one *problem*: a PictureBox can't be the active control (not using the default class style, it needs `ControlStyles.Selectable`). If you change `aControl.Location = (...)` with the name of a PictureBox (e.g., `pbSig.Location = (...)`, then the PictureBox will move and will accept a drop (provided you have `set pbSig.AllowDrop = True` somewhere), setting the new image. You have a typo in `pbSig_DragDrop` => `pbSig.ImageLocation = files(0)` should be `picbox.ImageLocation = files(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    KeyPreview = True
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        PictureBox1.Top -= 5
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
        PictureBox1.Top += 5
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
        PictureBox1.Left -= 5
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
        PictureBox1.Left += 5
    End If
End Sub
```

You can use this code to move the `PictureBox` using Arrow Keys.

Comment: The OP is already overriding `ProcessCmdKey`, which is the right thing to do (one of) in this scenario, since it will allows a correct processing of the Keys when automatic repetition is an option.

Comment: And I also stated that I can't use a KeyPress event since I am already using it elsewhere.  Unless...

Comment: @Mgfranz : For the record you can attach multiple event handlers to a single event. In VB.NET you either use `AddHandler` or (in cases like this) just create another method and make sure it has `Handles Me.KeyDown` on it. The actual name of the method isn't important. You could name it `Form1_KeyDown_2` or just as well `MyHappyBanana` if you'd like.

Comment: @Vincent, that is exactly what I was thinking.  Just making another event handler to handle KeyDown.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up using.  The Mouse just much better sense, plus I get to store it to Settings along with the other settings.  I think this is a good solution without getting into any DB work.  Opinions?

```
Private Sub CheckForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
'...
    pbSig.Location = My.Settings.pbSigLoc
'Allow an image to be dropped
    pbSig.AllowDrop = True
End Sub

End Sub
' The next three subs control the moving of the pbSig location using the mouse
Dim startX As Integer
Dim startY As Integer
Dim endX As Integer
Dim endY As Integer
Dim mDown As Boolean
Dim valX As Boolean
Dim valY As Boolean
Private Sub pbSig_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles pbSig.MouseDown
    startX = MousePosition.X
    startY = MousePosition.Y
    mDown = True
    valX = False
    valY = False
End Sub
Private Sub Main_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove

End Sub
Private Sub pbSig_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles pbSig.MouseMove
    'Check if mouse=down
    If mDown = True Then
        endX = (MousePosition.X - Me.Left)
        endY = (MousePosition.Y - Me.Top)
        If valY = False Then
            startY = endY - sender.top
            valY = True
        End If
        If valX = False Then
            startX = endX - sender.left
            valX = True
        End If
        sender.left = endX - startX
        sender.top = endY - startY
    End If
End Sub
'If mouseUp=True then End and Save to Settings
Private Sub pbSig_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles pbSig.MouseUp
    My.Settings.pbSigLoc = pbSig.Location
    mDown = False
    valX = False
    valY = False
End Sub
```

This way all the user needs to do is use their mouse to locate the pB and it's contents and I don't need to call the ProcessCmdKey again.  And I still have the arrow keys functionality on the Controls I need it to be.